# Ruby Gems Not Installing, Hangs While Getting Gems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, rubygems

I recently cleared out all of my ruby install and installed form sources using the instructions at [hivelogic](http://hivelogic.com/articles/compiling-ruby-rubygems-and-rails-on-snow-leopard)

I have have been able to install a few gems, but most of the time, "sudo gem install rails" 
hangs.  I've added the -V flag, and it just seems to hang, I don't get any error.  And the process can not be killed.  I can only reboot to kill the process.

My ruby info:

```
[tim@ ~]# ruby -v
ruby 1.8.7 (2010-01-10 patchlevel 249) [i686-darwin10.2.0]
[tim@ ~]# gem -v
1.3.6
[tim@ ~]# gem environment
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.3.6
  - RUBY VERSION: 1.8.7 (2010-01-10 patchlevel 249) [i686-darwin10.2.0]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /usr/local/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /usr/local/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86-darwin-10
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8
     - /Users/tim/.gem/ruby/1.8
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :benchmark => false
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
     - :sources => ["http://gems.rubyforge.org/", "http://gems.rubyforge.org"]
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - http://gems.rubyforge.org/
     - http://gems.rubyforge.org
[tim@ ~]# which ruby
/usr/local/bin/ruby
[tim@ ~]# which gem
/usr/local/bin/gem
[tim@ ~]# uname -a
Darwin tim-hoolihans-macbook-pro-15.local 10.2.0 Darwin Kernel Version 10.2.0: Tue Nov  3 10:37:10 PST 2009; root:xnu-1486.2.11~1/RELEASE_I386 i386
[tim@ ~]#
```

Any ideas?

Answer:

I built again with the following line and don't have the problem now:

```
ARCHFLAGS='-arch i386 -arch ppc -arch ppc64 -arch x86_64' sudo ./configure --enable--shared --enable-pthread CFLAGS=-D_XOPEN_SOURCE=1
```

Comment: A bit off-topic, but you can't kill with a -9? (ie, run "ps aux | grep gem", find the pid, and then do "kill -9 pid"?  Rebooting to kill a process seems harsh to me.  Could there be many things wrong with your system if -9 won't work?

Comment: kill -9 got it.  Thanks, I didn't know about that.  I thought -0 was the nuc version, but apparently -9 is it.

Comment: is http://gems.rubyforge.org responding quickly from your location.  I have found that if a remote server is not responding then gems can hang for a long time

Comment: Are you behind a firewall or NAT? Can you ping http://rubygems.org ? How about `curl http://rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz` or `curl http://rubygems.org/gems/rails-2.3.5.gem` ?

Comment: I was able to install gems fine (and quickly) from a linux machine behind the same router.

Comment: yes, sub 50ms pings.  plus i installed gems on a linux machine on the same network quickly.  not sure what the deal is, i just tried with a new gem tonight and it hung again.

Answer (score 318):

For me

```
sudo gem install rails -V
```

showed that it wasn't hanging, it was just taking a long time.

Comment: Upvoted.  While I'm still not convinced something else isn't wrong (it seems to be taking an unaccountably long time to do simple HTTP gets), the -V tells me *something* is happening.  Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Looks like I was running into the same issue.

Comment: And what if I've been waiting for one hour and all I see is:
'xStation> gem install rails -v 3.2.0 -V
GET 301 Moved Permanently: http://gems.rubyforge.org/specs.4.8.gz
GET 302 Moved Temporarily: https://rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz
GET 200 OK: https://s3.amazonaws.com/production.s3.rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz'

Comment: Perhaps it should be verbose by default?

Comment: Apparently, Ruby is still terribly slow.

Answer (score 10):

You probably just need to update your RVM.

Note that it's not really hanging so much as it's just taking 3 minutes to tell you whoops!  Should have used sudo.

From [this blog post](http://deanclatworthy.com/2012/12/how-to-fix-hanging-gem-install-on-a-fresh-osx-lion-install/) this on command line works:

```
curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --ruby
```

Answer (score 4):

I also experienced this issue. After installing ri1.8, it started to work properly (I use Ubuntu 10.04):

```
sudo apt-get -y install ri1.8
```

Answer (score 1):

Reason of slow working is convert RDoc into HTML during installation.
Just disable it via --no-rdoc --no-ri options.

```
gem install your_gem --no-rdoc --no-ri
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is really slow, check your network settings - especially if using a VM